# Keyboard LEDs versus Laptop LEDs

Tags: keyboard

I occasionally use an external keyboard with my laptop. Recently I put my hands on a nice old HP PS2 keyboard, and I'm planning to use that. The keyboard works fine, but I have one minor issue: the capslock and numlock LEDs don't work as they should. Specifically, when I activate capslock, it turns on the LED on the *laptop*, but not on the keyboard.

The LEDs on more recent keyboards work, or at least, they do for some time. For example I also use a Logitech K120 and the LEDs on that one work correctly.

I tried disabling the laptop keyboard through `xinput`, but that didn't help. Any suggestions?

The laptop is an ASUS N56V, I run Funtoo Linux, and the keyboard is an HP D4950B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this solved itself after the last kernel update.